# best way to store celery results

Tags: django, django-models, celery-task

I am using celery for my async tasks, however, I am using Redis as backend broker. My current plan is to filter and manipulate data inside the backend and store it into django-db for viewing etc.

Is this the recommended way? Or I should use Django DB as backend results db and  store all the raw data then filter and manipulate it into different tables?

Comment: There should be no problem with using Django database to store celery results, you could write own decorator that saves the response from each task into database. The Django db methods are supported in Celery, APScheduler and even async methods without problems.

Comment: try django-celery-results https://django-celery-results.readthedocs.io/en/latest/